# Get 4 equidistant values from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, int

Let's say I have an `NSArray` of 60 elements. Out of it, I would like to get 4 values at the indexes 15, 30, 45, 60. I was trying to put it into a for loop but it didn't work quite well here:

```
for (int elementIndex = x_valuesDataArray.count / 4; elementIndex < x_valuesDataArray.count; elementIndex = elementIndex + elementIndex){
    NSLog(@"Element index is %d", elementIndex);
    NSLog(@"Total values %u", x_valuesDataArray.count);
    NSString *firstValue = [x_valuesDataArray objectAtIndex:elementIndex];
    [xAxisArray02 addObject:firstValue];
}
```

But my `NSLog` output says I'm, doing something wrong:

```
2013-04-12 13:48:59.267 myApp[44682:907] Element index is 15
2013-04-12 13:48:59.269 myApp[44682:907] Total values 60
2013-04-12 13:48:59.270 myApp[44682:907] Element index is 30
2013-04-12 13:48:59.271 myApp[44682:907] Total values 60
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *15, 30, 60, 120, 240, ...* is exactly how `elementIndex = elementIndex + elementIndex` will grow.

Comment: the maths is not quite correct in your idea... if the count is `60` why do you start the enumeration at the `60/4 = ` 15th items...? you said you'd like to start with the 10th item... I think your problem is a problem of lack of the knowledge of elementary maths, huhh?

Comment: @holex being cynical, huh? The question had an error I fixed but forgot to fix the values. They look better now, don't you think?

Comment: @SergiusGee sorry, yes, sometimes I'm, because the origin of the error is so obvious now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    int elementIndex = x_valuesDataArray.count * i / 4 - 1;
    // ...
}
```

should work. Note that an array with 40 elements has indices 0 .. 39. In this case the above
loop gives the indices 9, 19, 29, 39. It is also assumed that the array has *at least* 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

A.  The x_valuesDataArray has 60 not 40 elements as you predicted.

B.  This line: `elementIndex = elementIndex + elementIndex` should be

```
elementIndex = elementIndex + 10
```

If the `valuesDataArray` was 40.

Comment: Yep, made a mistake there, it's 60